# Do glColorMask and glDrawBuffer accomplish the same thing?

Tags: opengl

I'm doing a shadowmap pass (only storing depth values) so I set `glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE)` to disable color writing for the moment.

Yet, I see some tutorials also do `glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE)`. Is this really necessary, given `glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE)`? Don't they accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of both of those functions, in general, is different:

`glDrawBuffer` controls writes to an *entire color buffer*. You can use it to enable or disable *all* writes to the front left, front right, back left, or back right buffers (or to some combination thereof).

`glColorMask`, however, controls writes of *entire color channels* to *all* color buffers (the related function, `glColorMaski` can be used to control entire color channels for a specific buffer).

In the case where you using the functions as specified, the effective result is the same for both calls: `glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE)` specifies that *no buffers* are to be drawn to, whereas `glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE)` specifies that no colors are to be written to all buffers.

In general, of course, the behavior is different. You'd use `glColorMask` if you wanted to only disable writes of the red color channel; `glDrawBuffer` does not give you that kind of granularity. However, `glColorMask` only makes sense in RGBA mode, but it has a nice parity with other masking functions like `glDepthMask`. Et cetera.

In the case where the effective result would be the same, you can choose whichever function you like best... and it doesn't make sense to do *both*, as you are implying some tutorials suggest.